# How to render prettified JSON in C# Razor templates?

Tags: c#, json, razor, razor-pages

I am trying to render formatted JSON as HTML using Razor Templates.
I am currently trying to do it like this:

```
<div>
    <pre>
        @JsonHelper.SerializeObject(item.AttributeValue, new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializerSettings() { 
            Formatting = Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented })
    </pre>
</div>
```

But once it gets to the browser, it is all on one line and looks something like this:

```
"{\"FieldA\":[{\"FieldAName\":\"start\",\"startValue\":\"startValue2\"},{\"FieldB\":\"FieldBsub\",\"FieldBValue\":\"SomeField\",\"Options\":[{\"ANumber\":1,\"Option\":\"LOL\"},{\"ANumber2\":2,\"Option\":\"LMAO\"},{\"ANumber3\":3,\"Option\":\"OTHER\"},{\"ANumber\":4,\"Option\":\"ROFL\"},{\"ANumber\":5,\"Option\":\"ROFL\"}]}],\"Choice\":\"yes\",\"fieldC\":\"yes\"}"
```

I am assuming the backslashes should be breaks that should be formatting it?
I am new to C# and I am pretty sure there is something wrong with the JSonHelper method? Maybe it is already a string?

Anyways I would like it to display like a formatted JSON in the browser view like this:
Just an example:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "5deeea2ed84c28fb633ecac8",
    "index": 0,
    "guid": "accc7f31-bfc7-4a42-9d76-a6f9f71e6f87",
    "tags": [
      "proident",
      "aute",
      "pariatur",
      "cupidatat",
      "officia",
      "adipisicing",
      "dolor"
    ],
    "friends": [
      {
        "id": 0,
        "name": "Alyson Scott"
      },
      {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Ratliff Castaneda"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Bernice Lester"
      }
    ],
    "greeting": "Hello, undefined! You have 6 unread messages.",
    "favoriteFruit": "banana"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a string property in my model that I set to a formatted JSON string

```
public string PortfolioJson { get; set; }

public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(int? rid) {
    PortfolioJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
}
```

Then on the page I just output that. I also use a JS library to pretty print the JSON.

```
@section Styles {
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/9.15.6/styles/default.min.css" />
}

<div class="row">
    <pre>
        <code class="json">
@Model.PortfolioJson
        </code>
    </pre>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/9.15.6/highlight.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();
    </script>
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to make a difference. The output in the HTML is still looking like the second code block in my original post?

Comment: I added in the link to the stylesheet I forgot to add in the OP. Have you tried with the JS highlight library?